# constexpr within method or namespace

Tags: c++, constexpr

I'm creating a `constexpr` array which is only used within the implementation of a method. I'm wondering what are the advantages/disadvantages of declaring this within the method vs. in the unnamed namespace (what I've always defaulted to).

```
void Foo::bar() {
  constexpr std::array<const uint8_t, 2> data = {0x00, 0x01};
  func(data);
}
```

vs.

```
namespace {
  constexpr std::array<const uint8_t, 2> data = {0x00, 0x01};
}
...
void Foo::bar() { func(data) }
```

Comment: Since you are passing it to a function, presumably as a const ref,  there is no advantage.

Comment: Well, strictly speaking, anonymous namespace would imply internal linkage and hence pollution of all the translation units. If you only need it inside your function it is kinda "better" to define it there (and mark it `static` as well, since it is `constexpr`).

Comment: @Dmitry Well this is debatable.. In terms of memory usage the namespace-option is "better". And what do you mean with all `translation units`? Only this one translation unit gets polluted because as you said, it has `internal linkage`.

Comment: Fun fact: assuming `func` takes argument by value and slightly bigger array (`std::array<uint8, 2>` is just passed as single integer), compiler optimises first version into simple dump of values to stack, but the second one has to read from memory: https://godbolt.org/z/9fGhKT5Wh. Eventually, it's a matter of style, as this is unlikely to have impact on performance (and if after profiling it turns out `func` really is the problem, there would be better ways to deal with the problem than these two options).

Comment: @EldinurtheKolibri Yeah, of course, I was assuming that namespace lives somewhere in a header file(and can be included multiple times). If all that is within cpp file I can't think of any distinguishable difference.

Answer (score 0):

Contrary to popular belief, `constexpr` automatic variables get initialized on **every** entry to the block like any other (non-static) local variables.  One can’t observe side effects from that initialization, since constant expressions can’t have any, but it’s observable if the function is recursive since the different calls give different addresses to the locals.  (Since any opaque function called by such a function `f` *might* call `f` recursively, the compiler has to allocate stack space for any such variable whose address might escape.)

Declaring the variable `static` avoids such a situation, but sometimes makes little difference since the optimization opportunities are the same if the address doesn’t escape.  It’s still in general preferable to a namespace definition for just the usual scope-minimization reasons.